# Adding Interactive Window to PDF matplotlib

Tags: pdf, matplotlib

Is it Possible to create interactive PDF using matplotlib?

[image: Plot]

[image: PDF]

Random code for Generating 3D scatter Plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[7,4,6,2,8],[4,6,8,9,2],'*')


with PdfPages("SystemPrediction3D.pdf") as pdf:# saving Pdf
    pdf.savefig(fig)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What makes you think matplotlib can create interactive PDFs?

Comment: My apologies, I rephrased my Question.

Comment: I still don't think it's possible, but maybe someone knows better.